# Why does this site have a large width?

Tags: css, width, document

On [this site](http://anitya.myconcretelab.com/) the document has a large width. When I'm inspecting it on Chrome, I don't see which element is causing this issue.

There are no elements that have this width.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by mistakes in the `<footer>` section.

You have `container` which forces width inside bootstrap column. You need to remove this class. See the attachment below.

The another problem is direct child inside `<section id="footer-bottom">`. It is element with class `row` which has negative horizontal margin. It also causes unwanted stretching of the entire website.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow:hidden` for this `.an.ccm-page`

add this style in your main.css

```
.an.ccm-page{
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the `<section id="footer-top">`. In the `<div class="col-sm-3">` you have another Bootstrap `.container`. If you're nesting Bootstrap grids do not use the `.container` class again and nest like e.g. `.row > .col-sm-3 > .row > .col-sm-12`.

In general if you want to know why your page is too wide: Open e.g. Chrome's DevTools, scroll to the right and start removing elements from the page. At the moment the page scrolls to the left again you know which element is too wide.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually because you have too many html tags mismatching in your markup, means opening tags without corresponging closing tags.

Refer: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fanitya.myconcretelab.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0